# Obtaining user's email id even if email is not verified

Tags: python, django, twitch

I am working on an application using Django/Python.
I am implementing Twitch Connect and I need email address of the user for my application.

My problem is that if the user has verified email id, i obtain it as apart of the django social auth pipeline in "details" argument.
However, if the user has not verified his/her email, 'email' key does not exist in details.

Is there any way I can ensure that email always flows through?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitch does not pass through unverified emails with a user's information. It's a valid API design choice.